# WebGoat on a separate computer?

Tags: kali-linux, webgoat

I was wondering if it's possible to have webgoat on one computer and access it from another computer running Kali Linux.
Detailed instructions would be very much appreciated

Comment: Welcome to InfoSec SE. Your question shows very little research effort.

Comment: https://github.com/WebGoat/WebGoat/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-get-configure-webgoat-to-run-on-an-ip-other-then-localhost

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is part of the instructions built in. See https://github.com/WebGoat/WebGoat/wiki/FAQ#local-host-ip-config